# How do I email my log4net log files upon them being rolled over?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, log4net

I have the following web.config

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="***************\\log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <!--max size roll backups: number of files produced before overridden (.count) after name-->
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="WARN" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="WARN" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

and email

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="**********@***.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="***" defaultCredentials="false" userName="**************" password=***********" enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Everything is working fine. I want however to email the a log file each time the files are rolled over... so when one is full and the next file starts being appended to I want to email the full one. I have no idea how to even start this...

Thanks

Comment: I haven't done this before, but my guess would be you'd need to build a new Appender class, maybe one deriving from `RollingFileAppender`, and add the email code there. Looking at the [source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/log4net/Appender/RollingFileAppender.cs?view=markup), you might be able to do it pretty easily just by overriding one or two of the virtual methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom appender inheriting from the `RollingFileAppender`, and override the AdjustFileBeforeAppend method in order to add mailing the file. Here is the existing method that rolls the file for the `RollingFileAppender` that you can modify.

Use the `File` property to find the file name and use the `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` to send the mail.

```
// log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender
protected virtual void AdjustFileBeforeAppend()
{
    if (this.m_rollDate)
    {
        DateTime now = this.m_dateTime.Now;
        if (now >= this.m_nextCheck)
        {
            this.m_now = now;
            this.m_nextCheck = this.NextCheckDate(this.m_now, this.m_rollPoint);
            // send the file here
            this.RollOverTime(true);
        }
    }
    if (this.m_rollSize)
    {
        if (this.File != null && ((CountingQuietTextWriter)base.QuietWriter).Count >= this.m_maxFileSize)
        {
            // send the file here
            this.RollOverSize();
        }
    }
}
```